# How to defined names header with many column

Tags: excel, dropdown

i want to create dropdown list with data validation.

i have an excel file with 517 column and with many different values for each column,
this is my data
[pict 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hTyu.png)

i want to defined names each header column, but its too many column

if i block them all (Ctrl+A) and "Create From Selection", there will be a blank values

[pict 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbDc3.png)

Comment: You want what? A dropdownlist that includes all the headers? Or instead of headers have a dropdown that include the values in that column? To me it's not that clear (since both screenshots also seem to represent a different sheet?)

Comment: yes, i want to create dependent dropdownlist. but there is too many column to create the headers defined names.

Comment: If you only have that many columns, I suggest you to manually create the named ranges one by one, and then update the named range with formula that dynamically looking up the range when there is change made to each column. At the moment there is no easier way to do it in excel (at least I have not seen a quicker way).